# Error when launching Azure VM from Image with Terraform due to SecurityType?

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm trying to launch a VM from Azure compute galleries that has the security type set to TrustedLaunch. I am getting this error when I run my apply:

```
Error: compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest" Message="The provided gallery image only supports creation of VMs and VM Scale Sets with 'TrustedLaunch' security type."
```

I read a post only 5 months ago that setting SecurityType isn't supported by Terraform. Is this true? If so, has anybody encountered this and found a workaround?

Cheers.

Tried searching and finding options to declare security_type with no luck

Comment: Please share the code you tried

Answer (score 0):

> I tried launching a VM from Azure compute galleries with the security type set to TrustedLaunch. I was able to provision it successfully.

Here we are working with **StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest Message="The provided gallery image only supports the creation of VMs and VM Scale Sets with 'TrustedLaunch' security type.** The issue can be resolved if we change the state of the image we create and also provide a null resource module by using Powershell.

My gallery image

[image]

**My terraform configuration:**

```
       data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
              name = "v-bolliv-Mindtree"
            }
        resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
              name                = "vkgallery"
              address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
              location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
              resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
            }
        resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
              name                 = "galleryintvk"
              resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
              virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
              address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
            }
        resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
              name                = "vmgalleryvk"
              location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
              resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
            
              ip_configuration {
                name                          = "testconfvksb"
                subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
                private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
              }
            }
        resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "testingvm" {
              name                        = "galimagevksb"
              resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
              location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
              vm_size                     = "Standard_DS1_v2"
              network_interface_ids       = [azurerm_network_interface.main.id]
            
              storage_image_reference {
                id = "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-2b83a074c23f/resourceGroups/v-bolliv-Mindtree/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/demoimagegalleryvk/images/demovkimage"  
                }
             storage_os_disk {
                name                      = "galleryimage-os1"
                caching                   = "ReadWrite"
                create_option             = "FromImage"
                managed_disk_type         = "Standard_LRS"
              }
               os_profile_windows_config {
            enable_automatic_upgrades = false
          }
        }
       }
     
    resource "null_resource" "resourcecli" {
      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = <<EOT
         command = $vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $vmName;$vm.OSProfile.SecurityType = "TrustedLaunch";Update-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -VM $vm
 }
    EOT
   interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
   }
 }
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use new resource types

```
"azurerm_windows_virtual_machine"
"azurerm_linux_virtual_machine"
```

instead of the old one

```
"azurerm_virtual_machine"
```

to provision Win/Linux VMs using Terraform in order to utilize new features like Trusted Launch by using secure_boot_enabled and/or vtpm_enabled properties.

More details:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/3.77.0/docs/resources/windows_virtual_machine.html#secure_boot_enabled