# The provided gallery image only supports creation of VMs and VM Scale Sets with 'TrustedLaunch' security type

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

When trying to create a VM with a gallery image using Terraform got the following error

**Error: compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest" Message="The provided gallery image only supports creation of VMs and VM Scale Sets with 'TrustedLaunch' security type."**

Although the image is created using a Trusted launch and there is no option to add code to the terraform script for Trusted Lunch (Tried *security_type *- An argument named "security_type" is not expected here, *trusted_launch_enabled *- An argument named "trusted_launch_enabled" is not expected here, *extended_security_configuration *- Blocks of type "extended_security_configuration" are not expected here) after applying all 3 options still no luck.

Is there a way to get it done?

Comment: Please share the code you tried

Comment: @VinayKumarBolli 
Here is the code
data "azurerm_shared_image_version" "existing" {
  name                = "1.0.0"
  image_name          = "PrimeSQLServer3"
  gallery_name        = "ACG_Nucsafe"
  resource_group_name = "RG-SharedNetServices"
}

Comment: resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                = var.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  vm_size               = var.vm_size
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.nic.id]
  license_type          = "Windows_Server"
  boot_diagnostics {
    enabled     = true
    storage_uri = ""
  }
  storage_image_reference {
    id = data.azurerm_shared_image_version.existing.id
  }

Comment: storage_os_disk {
    name              = "sqlvm-os"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76932257/error-when-launching-azure-vm-from-image-with-terraform-due-to-securitytype?rq=2 can you try including PowerShell using null resource in your terraform script

Comment: @VinayKumarBolli I tried using the PowerShell script but still got the same error TrustedLaunch. 
Manual deployment is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

> **The provided gallery image only supports creation of VMs and VM Scale Sets with 'TrustedLaunch' security type.**

The following error message will appear if you attempt to create a Virtual Machine using a gallery image that has the security type Trusted Launch: "The provided gallery image only supports creation of VMs and VM Scale Sets with 'TrustedLaunch' security type."

The `VM` that was produced from a `specialized image version` you will acquire the `osProfile` is not allowed due to an admin username and password problem. For further information, see to the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting-shared-images#creating-or-updating-a-vm-or-scale-sets-from-an-image-version)

To create a **VM** using a gallery image, try setting the security type to standard.

```hs
provider "azurerm"  {
      features {}
    }
    
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "venkat" {
      name = "resourcegroup"
    }
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
      name                = "gallery-network"
      address_space       = ["20.0.0.0/16"]
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    }
    resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
      name                 = "galleryinternal"
      resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
      address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
    }
    resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
      name                = "vmgallery-nic"
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    
      ip_configuration {
        name                          = "testconfiguration1"
        subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
      }
    }
    resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "testingvm" {
      name                        = "galleryimage"
      resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      vm_size                     = "Standard_DS1_v2"
      network_interface_ids       = [azurerm_network_interface.main.id]
    
      storage_image_reference {
        id = "/subscriptions/ahdjd d f hff-bd66-bfhffhf/resourceGroups/vmresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/galleryimage/images/galleryimage"  
        }
      storage_os_disk {
        name                      = "galleryimage-os"
        caching                   = "ReadWrite"
        create_option             = "FromImage"
        managed_disk_type         = "Standard_LRS"
      }
      os_profile {
        computer_name  = "venkatgalleryimage"
        admin_username = "Venkat"
        admin_password = "Password1234!"
      }
     os_profile_linux_config {
        disable_password_authentication = false
      }
    }
```

**Terraform apply**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Refer:  [Trusted launch VM Supported Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/trusted-launch-portal?tabs=powershell,powershell2,powershell3#trusted-launch-vm-supported-images)

Comment: How do I add setting security type to the standard?
I get 'An argument named "security_type" is not expected here' error.

Comment: It's not possible to create a VM from a gallery image with the security type Trusted Launch. Instead, you can create a VM with the security type Standard, and then define and deploy the VM using a gallery image.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar challenge. In the context of either the **azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scaleset** or **azurerm_windows_virtual_machine_scaleset**, there exists a crucial attribute named **[secure_boot_enabled](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine_scale_set#secure_boot_enabled)**. It is imperative to configure this attribute to *true* in order to successfully address and resolve the issue at hand.